# How do I set an output folder for my .wem converter?

Tags: batch-file, converters, ripping

I'm trying to make that when I run the script and there's a .wem file in my "input" folder, it will directly convert it into my "output" folder. But I can't seem to figure this out.

```
@Echo off
Echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
For %%f in ("%~dp0input\*.wem") do "./ww2ogg024/ww2ogg.exe" --pcb "./ww2ogg024/packed_codebooks_aoTuV_603.bin" "%%f"
For %%f in ("%~dp0outnput\*.ogg") do revorb.exe "%%f" 
Echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pause
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? I'm kind of a starter with this.

Comment: The best advice I can give you at this stage, is: `1.` Determine the command line options for your two executables, _(so that you know what information they need to perform the tasks you require of them)_. `2.` Find out how the `For` command works! _(Open up a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the 'Enter' key, and read all of the presented information)_.

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of your executables, however, a quick search revealed their command line options:

> ```batch-file
> ww2ogg input.wav [-o output.ogg] [--inline-codebooks] [--full-setup]
>                  [--pcb packed_codebooks.bin]
> ```
>
> ```batch-file
> revorb <input.ogg> [output.ogg]
> ```

From that information, I'd suggest that you try this sort of methodology, *(`Rem`arks included as explanation)*:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
Rem Define the location for ww2ogg.exe.
Set "WemToOggPath=C:\SomeLocation\ww2ogg024"
Rem Define the location for revorb.exe.
Set "MyRevorbPath=C:\SomeLocation"

Rem Exit if the required executables and input files are not available.
If Not Exist "%WemToOggPath%\ww2ogg.exe" Exit /B 1
If Not Exist "%MyRevorbPath%\revorb.exe" Exit /B 1
If Not Exist "%~dp0input\*.wem" Exit /B 1
Rem Create output directory if it does not already exist along side this script.
If Not Exist "%~dp0output\" MD "%~dp0output"

Echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rem Loop through each .wem file located inside the a directory named input along side this script.
For %%I In ("%~dp0input\*.wem") Do (
    Rem Run ww2ogg.exe against each .wem file outputting them to the same directory but with an .ogg extension.
    "%WemToOggPath%\ww2ogg.exe" "%%I" -o "%%~dpnI.ogg" --pcb "%WemToOggPath%\packed_codebooks_aoTuV_603.bin"
    Rem If the last ww2ogg.exe process was successful then.
    If Not ErrorLevel 1 If Exist "%%~dpnI.ogg" (
        Rem If there is still a .wem file delete it.
        If Exist "%%I" Del "%%I"
        Rem Run revorb.exe against the .ogg file outputting it to the output directory along side this script.
        "%MyRevorbPath%\revorb.exe" "%%~dpnI.ogg" "%~dp0output\%%~nI.ogg"
        Rem If the last revorb.exe process was successful and there is still a matching .ogg file inside the input directory delete it.
        If Not ErrorLevel 1 If Exist "%%~dpnI.ogg" If Exist "%~dp0output\%%~nI.ogg" Del "%%~dpnI.ogg"
    )
)
Echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pause
```

*As I don't know those utilities, I have tried to assume nothing, so if your conversion processes are not leaving the unconverted files behind, the script could probably be made smaller.*

Please read through the `Rem`arks to understand exactly what it does, before you run it, and most importantly, ensure that you modify `C:\SomeLocation` on lines `3` and `5` to those which hold your two executables. *(Please do not leave trailing path separators on those directories)*. I would then suggest that you try the script from within a test `input` directory, and against some copied `.wem` files, before attempting it in your production environment.